# Problem with multiprocessing pool in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing, numpy-ndarray

In my python code there is a For loop which reads files from a large list of filenames, reads information from these files and then write this information to a Numpy.ndarray. I realized that this for loop is taking a lot of time to complete and I can save time by parallelizing this process using `Multiprocessing.Pool()`

here is the for loop I wanted to parallelize looks like this (the actual code is different),

```
Matrix = [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],......[0,0,0]]
#a 2D numpy array of Zeros, this is where we want to write information to.

FileList = [file1,file2,file3....,fileN]
# a list containing the file names

for index in range (0,len(FileList)) :

   Data = ReadDataFromFile(FileList[index])
   #read some information from the file to the variable Data

   Matrix[M][N] = Data 
   # the value of Data is written to the MNth element of the matrix
```

I was trying to parallelize this, that is instead of the system reading one file at a time, I wanted it to read as much files as possible parallelly.

I could not find a way to parallelize the 'For loop', so by following some examples saw in Stackoverflow, I wrote the For loop in the form of a function and then used from `multiprocessing.Pool.map()` .

The function takes the filename as input, read the information from the file as given above, and then write this information to the Numpy.ndarray, which is already defined.Inside the function, I imported the array as `global` so that the modifications made inside the function will be available outside the function.

```
def GetDataFromFile(filename) :

    global Matrix 
    #calling Matrix as global variable

    Data = ReadData(filename) 

    Matrix[M][N]
    #writing information to global Matrix
```

when called, the function is working fine, and it is writing information to the array from file.

But when I tried to parallelize the process with  `multiprocessing. Pool.map()`

it is not working as expected, that is the modifications made by the function 'GetDataFromFile' is not changing the values of the ndarray globally.

```
import multiprocessing
p = multiprocessing.Pool()

Matrix = [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],......[0,0,0]]
#a 2D numpy array of Zeros, this is where we want to write information to.

FileList = [file1,file2,file3....,fileN]

def GetDataFromFile(filename) :

    global Matrix 
    #calling Matrix as global variable

    Data = ReadData(filename) 

    Matrix[M][N] 
    #writing information to global Matrix

p.map(GetDataFromFile,FileList)
print Matrix
```

The output of the above code gives all zeroes, that is the function is not adding information to the ndarray when used with `multiprocessing.Pool.map()` .

What is the problem here ?
How can we fix this? Is there any alternative way to achieve the same ?

Thanks in advance, I'm using Python2.7 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Comment: Just some advice, I wouldn't start variable names or function names with capital letters - only classes. Just a general consensus in the python community

Comment: global isn't enough in that case. You need `multiprocessing.Manager` objects.

Comment: you could try `multiprocessing.dummy` instead. It uses threads so shared variables would work. Shouldn't change much in your case since you perform a lot of I/O